# How to understand the error trace in Keras/Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

The error trace shown is quite complex and I am unable to understand it. Also, I wished to try the other way by printing shapes of tensors in every layer at the time of running the model but I found no function in keras which helps me do that.

Can anyone help me understand the error trace so that I can find a solution to remove the errors? Also, can anyone provide a trick to print shapes of tensors at model runtime?

Here's my model - https://github.com/ParikhKadam/bidaf-keras

Here's the error trace when calling `model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=1, validation_data=validate_generator, validation_steps=1, shuffle=False)`:

```
Epoch 1/1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ffa5706fca38> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=1, validation_data=validate_generator, validation_steps=1, shuffle=False)

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1416             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1417             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1418             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1419 
   1420     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    215                 outs = model.train_on_batch(x, y,
    216                                             sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 217                                             class_weight=class_weight)
    218 
    219                 outs = to_list(outs)

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)
   1215             ins = x + y + sample_weights
   1216         self._make_train_function()
-> 1217         outputs = self.train_function(ins)
   1218         return unpack_singleton(outputs)
   1219 

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
   2716         else:
   2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2674         else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2677 

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1380           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1381               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1382               run_metadata_ptr)
   1383         if run_metadata:
   1384           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    517             None, None,
    518             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 519             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    520     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    521     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: slice index 49 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
     [[Node: metrics/negative_avg_log_error/map/while/strided_slice_1 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](metrics/negative_avg_log_error/map/while/TensorArrayReadV3_1, metrics/negative_avg_log_error/map/while/strided_slice_1/stack, metrics/negative_avg_log_error/map/while/strided_slice_1/stack_1, metrics/negative_avg_log_error/map/while/strided_slice/stack_1)]]
     [[Node: training/Adadelta/gradients/query_to_context_attention/ExpandDims_grad/Reshape/_243 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_9091_...ad/Reshape", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]
```

Also, I don't know why but the error printed in command prompt is different than what I copied above (it's from jupyter notebook). The error printed on command prompt is as below:

```
2019-01-04 19:26:17.634769: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:105 : Invalid argument: slice index 49 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2019-01-04 19:26:17.646436: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:105 : Invalid argument: slice index 49 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2019-01-04 19:26:17.657683: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:105 : Invalid argument: slice index 54 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2019-01-04 19:26:17.671311: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:105 : Invalid argument: slice index 54 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
```

The first time it was **49** but at the end it produced **54**. I need help in understanding these parts of error trace:

```
InvalidArgumentError: slice index 49 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
     [[Node: metrics/negative_avg_log_error/map/while/strided_slice_1 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](metrics/negative_avg_log_error/map/while/TensorArrayReadV3_1, metrics/negative_avg_log_error/map/while/strided_slice_1/stack, metrics/negative_avg_log_error/map/while/strided_slice_1/stack_1, metrics/negative_avg_log_error/map/while/strided_slice/stack_1)]]
```

and

```
[[Node: training/Adadelta/gradients/query_to_context_attention/ExpandDims_grad/Reshape/_243 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_9091_...ad/Reshape", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Also, I don't know if these two errors are related to each other..